# perl get the first matched word in a line

Tags: perl

Sorry im new in perl and cannot find a similar answer.

html file

```
<div class="user_rating">
.
.
<span class="genre">
.
.
.
<span class="genre">
.
.
.
<span class="genre">
.
.
.
<span class="genre">
```

perl file

```
$content =~ /<div class="user_rating">(.*)<span class="genre">/gs;
$empty = $1;
```

this $empty variable contains information from `<div class="user_rating">` to the last `<span class="genre">`.

But i just want the information from `<div class="user_rating">` to the first `<span class="genre">`.
how should i modify my code? i know it is a regular expression problem.

Any help plz...

Comment: If you are going to do a lot of HTML parsing, look into something like `HTML::TreeBuilder` (http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm), which will parse the HTML for you.  A regex is certainly a useful quick-and-dirty solution for tasks like this, but it is not a robust way of processing HTML in general.

Comment: [Don't try to parse HTML with regexps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/470535) yourself, use a [HTML parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your regexp, because `.*` is greedy.

```
$content =~ /<div class="user_rating">(.*?)(<span class="genre">){1}/gs;
```

Comment: @user1767718 Welcome on SO! If this answer worked for you, you may want to *accept* it as well. But also consider the parser hints in the question's comments :)